# Vuex not returning expected state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuex

I have a pop up modal that should appear if the user has no transactions. `depositHistory` is an array with these transactions. If its length is greater than 0, the pop up should remain hidden. If its length is equal to 0, the pop up should render.

The user account I'm using has 2 transactions. The pop up shouldn't show but it does. The `console.log()` returns an empty array which is not correct. I have another component someone else wrote which uses `depositHistory` in the same way and is working as expected.

**Component:**

```js
<template>
  <div v-if='renderModal'>
    <p>Fund your account</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const DepositGetter = namespace("deposit").Getter

const AppProps = Vue.extend({
data: () => {
  return {
    renderModal: false
  }
},
beforeMount() {
  // renders modal if user has no transactions
  if (this.depositHistory.length === 0) this.renderModal = true

  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.depositHistory)))
  // usually returns [__ob__: Observer]
  // added JSON methods so now it logs []
}

export default class HomeGameBanner extends AppProps {
  @DepositGetter depositHistory
}
</script>
```

I don't think you need this but just in case.

**Store:**

```js
type DepositGetter = GetterTree<DepositState, RootState>;

export const getters: DepositGetter = {
  depositHistory: state => state.content
};

export const deposit: Module<DepositState, RootState> = {
  getters
}
```

Comment: Is the transaction data being loaded from an API? If so, the problem might be that you do not trigger the loading of this data, and/or access it before it has been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

the data object is initialized after `beforeMount` so try and execute in `mounted`
like this

```
<template>
  <div v-if='renderModal'>
    <p>Fund your account</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const DepositGetter = namespace("deposit").Getter

const AppProps = Vue.extend({
data: () => {
  return {
    renderModal: false
  }
},
mounted() {
this.$nextTick(function () {
  // renders modal if user has no transactions
  if (this.depositHistory.length === 0) this.renderModal = true

  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.depositHistory)))
  // usually returns [__ob__: Observer]
  // added JSON methods so now it logs []
})
}

export default class HomeGameBanner extends AppProps {
  @DepositGetter depositHistory
}
</script>
```

### Fore reference

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately it didn't change anything